# How do you make Windows Defender Firewall rule for MS Teams to work?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-teams, windows-firewall, windows-defender

I'm currently configuring Windows Defender on Windows 10 setting up such that only restricted apps can be run.

In one of the allowed apps, I want to have Microsoft Teams be able to run under this environment.

I added the following exe files as allowed programs under "send rules".

- AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe
- AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe

but so far no luck.

If anyone could guide me on how to configure it correctly, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer directly to %appdata% generically across all users. A firewall rule needs to be created per instance of Teams i.e. per user.

You can use the Microsoft suggested sample PowerShell script to set up a firewall rule per existing user on a workstation. Available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/get-clients#sample-powershell-script---inbound-firewall-rule

This doesn't help for the next user who logs into the workstation when there is no firewall rule preemptively created for them.

You will have to create a scheduled task to create a firewall rule ( or check for whether one exists already) on user logon.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce19d9e3-e1ec-48dc-a706-82a9840394a2/allow-exe-located-through-windows-firewall-that-is-located-in-userprofile?forum=w7itprosecurity

GPO: Windows Defender Firewall: Define inbound program exceptions

Define program exceptions:

Registry Hive   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Registry Path   SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\DomainProfile\AuthorizedApplications\List
Value Name  {number}
Value Type  REG_SZ
Default Value
Specify the program to allow or block.

Syntax:

:::

is the program path and file name

is either "*" (for all networks) or

a comma-separated list that contains

any number or combination of these:

IP addresses, such as 10.0.0.1

Subnet descriptions, such as 10.2.3.0/24

The string "localsubnet"

is either "enabled" or "disabled"

is a text string

Example:

The following definition string adds the

TEST.EXE program to the program exceptions list

and allows it to receive messages from 10.0.0.1,

or any system on the 10.3.4.x subnet:

%programfiles%\test.exe:10.0.0.1,10.3.4.0/24:enabled:Test program

Comment: Some formatting might be in order to improve legibility